# Initializing server for displaying hello using node.js cannot resolve

Tags: node.js

I am trying node.js as a possible technology as oppose to traditional php server for my school project, I am trying to initiate a server that prints hello, but for some reason my localhost won't display that, it only waits for localhost for a long time. Any help would be appreciated

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on("end", function () {
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `request.on("end")`:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8080);
```